# Reduce: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I got the error message 'Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.'

Here is my code

```
neweqns = {Sin[a] + Sin[a - b] + Sin[a - c] == 0 && 
 Sin[a - b] == Sin[b] + Sin[b - c] && Sin[a] + Sin[c] == Sin[b] && 
 Sin[a - c] + Sin[b - c] == Sin[c]}

result = Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 π && 0 <= b <= 2 π && 
   0 <= c <= 2 π, {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: You should explain what you are going to achive, what the symbols are inteded to describe and you shouldn't use illegible (for the most of users) signs.  'Text...' doesn't seem to generate problems and so it is a bad idea to include it into your code, it should be a minimal example instead.

Comment: @Artes Yes, thank you. I just edited the code. I hope it looks more straightforward now.

Comment: Notation `[something]` is incorrect without the head of a function.    The system includes `4` equations and only `3` unknown variables and so it is an overdetermined system.  Although there are solutions,  they are easy to guess.

Comment: You cannot use function brackets (`[ ]`) in place of parentheses (`( )`). Then use `TrigExpand` on `neweqns`.

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't understand. which ```[]``` brackets, the one in ```Reduce```? Thank you!

Comment: @Artes yes, the equations indeed have reductions. But I don't understand why the reductions stop ```Reduce``` to produce the solutions?

Comment: Prior to an edit, in the definition of `neweqns` the RHS was bracketed in function brackets rather than the current list brackets.

Comment: @BobHanlon  yep, my previous post is: ```neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol]```. Do you mean this line?

Comment: When I saw the post the `FullSimplify` wasn't there. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BobHanlon Ah, okay. thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us expand sines of differences, then `Reduce` can crack it.

```
newesteqns =  Sin[a] + Sin[a]*Cos[b] - Cos[a]*Sin[b] + Sin[a]*Cos[c] - 
Cos[a]*Sin[c] == 0 &&  Sin[a]*Cos[b] - Cos[a]*Sin[b] == 
Sin[b] + Sin[b]*Cos[c] - Cos[a]*Sin[c] &&  Sin[a] + Sin[c] == Sin[b] &&  
Sin[a]*Cos[c] - Cos[a]*Sin[c] + Sin[b]*Cos[c] - Cos[b]*Sin[c] == 
Sin[c];
result = Reduce[newesteqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi] && 
0 <= c <= 2 \[Pi], {a, b, c}, Reals]
```

> `a == \[Pi] && ((b ==  0 && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] ||  c == 2 \[Pi])) || (b == \[Pi] && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] ||  c == 2 \[Pi])) || (b ==  2 \[Pi] && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi])))) || (b ==  0 && ((a == 0 && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi])) || (a ==  2 \[Pi] && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] ||  c == 2 \[Pi])))) || (b == \[Pi] && ((a ==  0 && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi])) || (a ==  2 \[Pi] && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi])))) || (b ==  2 \[Pi] && ((a ==  0 && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi])) || (a ==  2 \[Pi] && (c == 0 || c == \[Pi] || c == 2 \[Pi]))))`

Comment: you can also use `TrigExpand` to do the expansion: `Reduce[And @@ TrigExpand@neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= c <= 2 \[Pi], {a, b, c}, Reals]`  (+1)

Comment: @kglr: Thank you for your valuable comment.